# Database design for list of US Senators in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing a table that simply keeps a list of current US Senators and some related information (much of which I'm getting from the awesome NY Times Congress API). Creating the table for Representatives was easy, because I just created a `PRIMARY KEY` on their `state` and `district number`. This has stumped me, though.

I need to be updating the information in this table nightly, and will be doing an `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Any thoughts on how to go about designing this?

Comment: Why are you using INSERT to update existing information? That's what UPDATE is for.

Comment: Er, good question, for which I have no good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `UPDATE` rather than an insert, checking first if the record exists by querying for the composite key values.

You don't say what database you're using, but SQL Server 2008 has a `MERGE` statement that accomplishes this very easily.

Comment: The real problem I'm having is that I'm not sure what primary key to even create for the senators. There are 2 senators per state, and since every other data field about them can change, I'm honestly not sure what to use to distinguish the two senators.

Comment: Why not use their names? Or a combination of Last Name + State.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is what to use for the primary key, why not make the primary key on the first name, last name, and state? That convention could be used for both senators and representatives.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use INSERT to update existing data, use UPDATE and your PK for that.

You say elsewhere that you're having trouble choosing a PK because each state has two senators and you don't know how to differentiate them. US senators are grouped into [three classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classes_of_United_States_Senators) and no two senators from a single state are in the same class so your PK could be state and class.